# Multiple Checkbox Saving to DB 1 or 0

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravel-blade

Creating multiple question checkboxes and I need to send two possible cases 1 or 0 to the database. However, it always sends the last one I click as 1 all the others 0. So for example, if a user clicks/checks the first one and the last I want to send to the database both 1 and the other two unchecked 0.

**Controller**

```
<?php

public function create($request)
{
    foreach ($request['options'] as $key => $option) {
        Answer::create([
            'question_id' => $this->get(),
            'text' => $option,
            'correct' => $request['correct'] == $key ? 1 : 0
        ]);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@for($i = 1; $i<=4; $i++)
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('options.'.$i) ? ' has-error': '' }}" id="option{{ $i }}">
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-2 control-label" style="margin-top: -2px">
            <label>
                <input id="cc" type="checkbox" name="correct" value="{{$i}}" {{ $i==1 ? 'checked' : '' }} >
            <!--
            {!! Form::hidden('correct',0) !!}
            {!! Form::checkbox('correct',1,false) !!}
            -->
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" name="options[{{ $i }}]" value="{{ old('options.'.$i) }}"
                   class="form-control" placeholder="@lang('general.option') {{ $i }}">
            @if($errors->has('options.'.$i))
                <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('options.'.$i) }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
@endfor
```

Comment: Add hidden Input field corresponding to each check box field. set default value to 0 and change the input field value on check box click using java script.

Comment: I tried doing this way    <input   type="hidden" name="correct" value="0" >                                                                                                         
  <input  id="cc" type="checkbox" name="correct"  value="1" {{ $i==1 ? 'checked' : '' }}  >                                                             
                                              
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).attr('value', '1');
  } else {
    $(this).attr('value', '0');
  }

});  But now is sending all the inputs 1

Comment: If checked then you have to change value of hidden input field, you are changing value of check box it self. Hope you understand

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort to help me, but I  think that this hidden input it is not making any change, I think it is not playing any role here.. :/

Comment: when you checked a check box, please check the checked event in java script and you can inspect the input fields to see values are changed or not .

Answer (score 0):

Either mention array of control for checkbox as below

```
 <input  id="cc" type="checkbox" name="correct[]" value="{{$i}}" {{ $i==1 ? 'checked' : '' }}  >
```

change **`name="correct"`** to **`name="correct[]"`**

OR

give different name to each checkbox using incremental variable like

**`name="correct"`** to **`name="correct_".$i`**

Comment: Thank but it is not working,  name="correct[]" it is sending all 0

Comment: can you add a snap of your view?